# Flutter how to create a ListView and display based on condition

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a list like this:

```
List<ProductModel> productList = [
    ProductModel(name: "Oranges", price: "150"),    
    ProductModel(name: "Apples", price: "80"),
];
```

And I want to display the list as the first image below:

[image]

However, I only manage to display it like this:

[image]

How should I change my code in order to display the red and blue containers only once?

Here is my oversimplified code:

```
class ProductListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ProductListPageState();
}

class _ProductListPageState extends State<ProductListPage> {
  late StreamController<int> _postsController;
  List<ProductModel> productList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _postsController = new StreamController();
    getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getProducts() {
    Fetch.getProdcuts().then((value) => {
      _postsController.add(1),
      productList.addAll(value!)
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text("This is a Product List"),
                  ]),
            ),
            products(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget products() {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: _postsController.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return productsView();
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Empty'),
            );
          }
        });
  }

  Widget productsView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: productList.length,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final p = productList[index];
          return  Container(
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(                        //Show this Container once
                    child: const Text('Expensive'),
                  ),
                  p.price! >= 100 ?
                    Container(
                      child: Text(p.name! + ": $" + p.price.toString()),
                    )
                    : Container(),
                  const SizedBox(                   //Show this SizedBox once
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                  Container(                        //Show this Container once
                    child: const Text('Cheap'),
                  ),
                  p.price! < 100 ?
                    Container(
                      child: Text(p.name! + ": $" + p.price.toString()),
                    )
                    : Container(),
                ]),
          );
        });
  }
}

class ProductModel extends Object {
  String? name;
  double? price;

  ProductModel({this.name, this.price});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json["name"];
    price = json["price"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'price': price,
  };
}
```

I tried adding a `bool` variable and changing it to true once the `Expensive` or `Cheap` containers are displayed but it didn't work.
I guess I should change the structure of the entire list but I cannot seem to find the right approach.
Any suggestions?

Comment: should it be always two item on `productList`?

Comment: No, it can be more, hence the problem...

Comment: what is the margin/logic/separator between expensive vs cheap

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you asking how we determine whether a product is expensive or cheap?

Comment: yap, how do  you determine it

Comment: It's a fixed condition - if above $100 it's expensive, else it's cheap.

Comment: try raw-chicken's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having one `ListView.builder`, use two. Insert logic for when you are getting your product list to separate out into the cheap and expensive like so:

```
void getProducts() {
  Fetch fetch = Fetch();
  fetch.getProdcuts().then((value) {
    _postsController.add(1);
    debugPrint(value.toString());
    for (var item in value) {
      debugPrint(item.toString());
      final price = double.parse(item["product"]["price"]);
      final name = item["product"]["name"];
      final json = {"name": name, "price": price};
      final product = ProductModel.fromJson(json);
      if (price >= 100) {
        expensiveProductList.add(product);
      } else {
        cheapProductList.add(product);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Then for productView, make a column with your headers and the two lists for cheap and expensive. That was the headers show up only once and you get your populated lists. Here's a sample of what it may look like:

```
Widget productsView() {
  return Column(children: [
    Container(
      //Show this Container once
      child: const Text('Expensive'),
    ),
    Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: expensiveProductList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final p = expensiveProductList[index];
              return Container(
                child: Text("${p.name!}: ${p.price.toString()}"),
              );
            })),
    Container(
      // Show this Container once
      child: const Text('Cheap'),
    ),
    Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cheapProductList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final p = cheapProductList[index];
              return Container(
                child: Text("${p.name!}: ${p.price.toString()}"),
              );
            })),
  ]);
}
```

There may be some issues with the above code since it's simplified down, but you should be able to follow a similar format to achieve what you want.

#### Full Example

```
class ProductListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductListPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ProductListPageState();
}

class _ProductListPageState extends State<ProductListPage> {
  late StreamController<int> _postsController;
  List<ProductModel> cheapProductList = [];
  List<ProductModel> expensiveProductList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _postsController = StreamController();
    getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getProducts() {
    fetch.getProdcuts().then((value) {
      _postsController.add(1);
      debugPrint(value.toString());
      for (var item in value) {
        debugPrint(item.toString());
        final price = double.parse(item["product"]["price"]);
        final name = item["product"]["name"];
        final json = {"name": name, "price": price};
        final product = ProductModel.fromJson(json);
        if (price >= 100) {
          expensiveProductList.add(product);
        } else {
          cheapProductList.add(product);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child: products()),
    );
  }

  Widget products() {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: _postsController.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return productsView();
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Empty'),
            );
          }
        });
  }

  Widget productsView() {
    return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
      Container(
        //Show this Container once
        child: const Text('Expensive'),
      ),
      Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: expensiveProductList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final p = expensiveProductList[index];
                return Container(
                  child: Text("${p.name}: ${p.price.toString()}"),
                );
              })),
      Container(
        // Show this Container once
        child: const Text('Cheap'),
      ),
      Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: cheapProductList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final p = cheapProductList[index];
                return Container(
                  child: Text("${p.name}: ${p.price.toString()}"),
                );
              })),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This is definitely something I haven't thought of. Now, I am faced with another challenge - my `value` is the following: `[{"id":38,"product:{"name":"Oranges","price":"150"}},{"id":39,"product:{"name":"Apples","price":"80"}]`. How do I access each `price` to compare to 100?

Comment: Is getProdcuts retrieving a list of products, or just the JSON?

Comment: Just the Json that I shared. After that I map the JSON to the ProductModel class.

Comment: @BradG take a look at the edit of the solution to see if it works like this. Since `value` is a list of Maps, you can iterate through them and use the values just like you normally would with maps.

Comment: Humm, I am getting couple of alerts: `The value of the local variable 'item' isn't used. ` for `(var item in value)` and  `Expected an identifier. Expected to find '}'.` for `final price...`

Comment: You are probably missing some bracket somewhere. Additionally, I've edited a bit of the code so that the conversions are correct.

You're passing in the price in the JSON as a string, but your model uses doubles, you probably want to make this consistent. I've revised the code so that it converts it to a product model properly.